# C#: how to set value of "X" equal to zero when "List1" name is not in "list2"

Tags: c#

Condition 1: In below code sometime `list2` is null, hence I make a check like,
`list2 == null ? 0 : list2.Wher.....`

Condition 1: Some of `list1` name also not in `list2`, for that I want to set `Age` = 0

how to satisfy both condition?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new List<List1> { new List1 { Name = "A1" }, new List1 { Name = "A2" } };

        //sometime my "list2" is null as well
        //var list2 = null;
        var list2 = new List<List2> { new List2 { Name = "A1", Age = 10 } };

        foreach (var a in list1)
        {
            var X = list2 == null ? 0 : list2.Where(x => x.Name == a.Name).FirstOrDefault().Age;
        }
    }
}

public class List1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class List2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your output

Comment: currently, exception is coming. reason list1 name `A2` not in list2

Comment: You can use `.DefaultIfEmpty(new List2 { Age = 0 }).First().Age`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `foreach` loop at all.

you can solve like this:

```
var x = list2 == null ? 0 : 
     list2.Where(x => list1.Any(e => x.Name == e.Name)).FirstOrDefault()?.Age ?? 0;
```

or another variant would be:

```
var x = list2 == null ? 0 : 
      list2.FirstOrDefault(x => list1.Any(e => x.Name == e.Name))?.Age ?? 0;
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` accepts a predicate; would moving the predicate from `Where` to `FirstOrDefault` result in the same output? This would simplify the call slightly.

Comment: Like this perhaps: `var x = list2?.FirstOrDefault(x => list1.Any(e => x.Name == e.Name))?.Age ?? 0`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach (var a in list1)
{
    var X = list2 == null ? 0 : (list2.Where(x => x.Name == a.Name).FirstOrDefault()?.Age ?? 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at [This Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.110).aspx). It explains the `.DefaultIfEmpty` that I will use.

`DefaultIfEmpty` will:

> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the specified value in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

What you can do in your case to satisfy both conditions in the next:

```
var X = list2 == null ? 0 : list2.Where(x => x.Name == a.Name).DefaultIfEmpty(new List2 { Age = 0 }).First().Age;
```